# Magento 2 frontend and admin pages are not rendering often

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.0

I have installed Magento 2.1.0 with url http://127.0.0.1/magento-2.1.0-blank, then i have enabled developer mode, run static deploy command and compiled command its working fine for sometime. after sometime when i tried front end and back end pages, its continuously loading and not rendering anymore. I'm facing this problem often. What could be the solution? I'm using xampp with windows. I'm running magento 2 in developer mode so please suggest solution accordingly.

Comment: I am also facing same problem. any help would be appreciated.